# Managed entity is not getting persisted into the DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have got the below method :-

```
public Staff authenticateStaff(LoginBean loginBean) {
        staff = staffDao.findUnique(loginBean.getUserName());
        if (null != staff) {
            if (staff.getIsBlocked() == 'N' && staff != null && staff.getUserName().equals(loginBean.getUserName())
                    && staff.getPassword().equals(loginBean.getPassword())) {
                staff.setLastLogin(new Date());
                new StaffDaoImpl().update(staff);
                return staff;
            } else if (staff.getIsBlocked() == 'N' && staff != null
                    && staff.getUserName().equals(loginBean.getUserName())) {
                updateUnsuccessfulAttemptsAndBlockedStatus(staff);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In this method you will see that the staff is a managed Entity and I am calling the below method 'updateUnsuccessfulAttemptsAndBlockedStatus' passing the staff managed entity.

```
public void updateUnsuccessfulAttemptsAndBlockedStatus(Staff staff) {
        int unsuccessfullLoginAttempts = staff.getUnsuccessfullLoginAttempts();
        staff.setUnsuccessfullLoginAttempts(unsuccessfullLoginAttempts + 1);
        if (unsuccessfullLoginAttempts + 1 > NOOFALLOWEDUNSUCCESSFULATTEMPTS)
            staff.setIsBlocked('Y');
        new StaffDaoImpl().update(staff);
    }
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="expenseCalculator"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expenseCalc" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="dbauser" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="abcdefg" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /> -->
            <!-- Enabling Second Level Cache -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

MyDaoImpl Class:-

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "expenseCalculator";
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    protected static EntityManager em;
    protected EntityTransaction etr;

    protected Class<T> domainClass;
    /** The domain object name. */
    protected String domainObjectName = null;

    public synchronized static EntityManagerFactory getfactory(){
        if (null == factory) {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        }
        return factory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDaoImpl() {
        em = getfactory().createEntityManager();
        domainClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Entity entityAnn = (Entity) domainClass.getAnnotation(Entity.class);
        if (entityAnn != null && !entityAnn.name().equals("")) {
            domainObjectName = entityAnn.name();
        } else {
            domainObjectName = domainClass.getSimpleName();
        }
    }

public T update(T t) {
        etr = em.getTransaction();
        etr.begin();
        etr.commit();
        return t;
    }
```

After the users unsuccessful login the method 'updateUnsuccessfulAttemptsAndBlockedStatus' is called. But the value of attributes of the Staff table are not getting persisted into the DB as the Staff entity is not remaining managed.

Can anyone please explain why is the staff entity becoming unmanaged?

Comment: The "update" method doesn't do anything to any object, so hardly surprising that it does not persist ...

Comment: @NeilStockton If the Entity is managed (that is inside the persistent context) then we do not need persist() or merge() method as em will detect the change to it..Now In my method 'updateUnsuccessfulAttemptsAndBlockedStatus' if I do "Staff staff=new StaffDaoImpl().findUnique(staff.getUserName())" and execute the changes are reflected in the DB because now the Staff entity is getting managed in the persistence context.

Comment: There is NOTHING in the code you present to say "staff" is a managed entity. You present only one use of an EntityManager and that is in "update", which does sweet fa. Also the persistence context is defined by the persistence.xml; you haven't provided it.

Comment: @NeilStockton Details provided ..plz check now.

Comment: Make use of `em.contains` to find where any possible problem of becoming unmanaged lies ...

Answer (score 0):

For managed entities Hibernate automatically synchronizes the entity state with the underlying database record. But you should handle entities inside of persistence context.

Move `authenticateStaff` method to `GenericDaoImpl` and change it like this:

```
    public Staff authenticateStaff(LoginBean loginBean) {
        etr = em.getTransaction();
        etr.begin();
        staff = staffDao.findUnique(loginBean.getUserName());
        if (null != staff) {
            if (staff.getIsBlocked() == 'N' && staff != null && staff.getUserName().equals(loginBean.getUserName())
                    && staff.getPassword().equals(loginBean.getPassword())) {
                staff.setLastLogin(new Date());
 etr.commit();
                return staff;
            } else if (staff.getIsBlocked() == 'N' && staff != null
                    && staff.getUserName().equals(loginBean.getUserName())) {
                int unsuccessfullLoginAttempts = staff.getUnsuccessfullLoginAttempts();
                staff.setUnsuccessfullLoginAttempts(unsuccessfullLoginAttempts + 1);
                if (unsuccessfullLoginAttempts + 1 > NOOFALLOWEDUNSUCCESSFULATTEMPTS)
                    staff.setIsBlocked('Y');
            }
        }
 etr.commit();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I know that this code will work. My question is that y is my code not working?

Comment: because your entity handling logic is out of persistence context

Comment: I know it is out of persistence context but my question is y?